# Separate loading prop for each "subquery"

Tags: react-apollo

I move all seperate querys into my main viewing component and pass the data via props to each component. So I can have a single query request for each page instead of 5 or 6.

Now I'm facing my first problem. I have 2 querys with variables and when I modify a variable it set the `data:{ loading }` prop to `true` so my whole interface is showing a loading spinner even if only one thing is actually loading.

[Here how it lookls like if I press a button on the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLoZq.png)

My query object looks like this:

```
const query = gql`
  query SumaryPage($limitIOChart: Int!, $limitAHChat: Int!) {
    IOBalance: getIncomeOutcome(limit: 1) {
      income
      outcome
      total
    }
    AccountBalanceData: getAccountBalance {
      id
      name
      balance
    }
    TransactionHistoryData: getTransactions(limit: 5) {
      id
      name
      amount
      date
      type
    }
    IOChart: getIncomeOutcome(limit: $limitIOChart, orderBy: ASC) {
      month
      year
      income
      outcome
    }
    AmountHistoryData: getAmountHistory(limit: $limitAHChat, orderBy: ASC) {
      month
      year
      amount
    }
  }
`;
```

Is there a better approach to still have a single query per "page" but avoid having only a single loading prop?

Comment: Mhh probably need to split each query in its own `query` thing and (somehow) merge them together to have as little as possible http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've probably found the solution for this.

1. Split each "subquery" in its own query element.
2. use `compose` to merge all querys together

Something like this:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(`query { ... }`),
  graphql(`query { ... }`),
  graphql(`query { ... }`),
)(MyComponent);
```

As you can see here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#compose